# Participemos en la Encuesta para Desarrolladores 2021

Tags: discusión, encuesta-para-desarrolladores

> Esta es una traducción de [Take the 2021 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey) por [Stephanie ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10624141/stephanie)

¡Nuestra encuesta para desarrolladores de 2021 se abrió hoy! Ya seas un miembro activo de la comunidad de Stack Overflow o no, animamos a todos los que codifican a participar y hacer oír su voz. La encuesta estará abierta hasta el 15 de junio y solo debería tomar unos 10 minutos para completarla (eso es diez minutos menos que el año pasado).

[Responde la encuesta](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_7arimtzVFf8ipfM)

Como sucedió en años anteriores, cualquier usuario que complete la encuesta en su totalidad obtendrá la medalla Censo. Tendrá la opción de obtener la insignia en Stack Overflow o en un sitio diferente dentro de la red de Stack Exchange.

Los resultados de la encuesta anonimizados estarán disponibles públicamente bajo la Open Database License. Podrás descargar y analizar el conjunto de datos a finales de este año. Ciertas respuestas de la encuesta se tratan como información de identificación personal y, por lo tanto, se excluyen de los resultados anónimos. Estas preguntas se destacan en la encuesta con una nota que dice: "Esta información se mantendrá privada".

Gracias de antemano por su tiempo y, además, gracias a todos los que nos dieron sus comentarios sobre [nuestra lista de tecnologías](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407253/review-our-languages-and-platforms-for-dev-survey-2021) para la versión de este año.

Si usas extensiones de seguridad o de bloqueo de anuncios, es posible que veas mensajes de error. Nuestro proveedor de software externo, Qualtrics, no funciona bien con ciertos bloqueadores de anuncios y software de seguridad. Para evitar mensajes de error que te impidan realizar la encuesta, intenta desbloquear específicamente Qualtrics en su extensión o pausar el complemento mientras realizas la encuesta. Además, como recordatorio, Qualtrics bloquea el acceso de ciertos países a su sitio e información: Cuba, Irán, Corea del Norte, Siria y la región de Crimea en Ucrania (incluida Sebastopol). Además, algunos usuarios en China pueden tener problemas debido a las restricciones impuestas por los proveedores de servicios de Internet locales.

Si hay algún error, pregunta o inquietud, le recomendamos que lo agregue a [esta publicación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey) como respuesta.

¡¡Gracias!!

Comment: Hola, yo no puedo hacer la encuesta ya que el gobierno americano por problemas politicos con el gobierno de mi pais bloquea esa pagina, alguien podria por favor explicarme bien de que trata esa encuesta a ver si me entero por lo menos de algo

Comment: @Japv Pregunta que tecnologias usas, cuales quieres aprender, cuales te gustan, etc. Ademas hay unas preguntas mas personales estilo tus estudios o tu trabajo.

Comment: Buena encuesta, sobre todo porque no sabía que yo tenía tantas enfermedades.

Comment: Este año ha sido una encuesta muy corta y me ha dado la sensación que la mitad de la encuesta se componía de preguntas habituales y la otra mitad de gilipo####s que no tienen nada que ver con el desarrollo de software.